# Functors in Java

Tags: java, haskell, category-theory

I'm trying to define classes in Java that are similar to Haskell's functors. Hereby, a functor is defined as:

```
/**
 * Programming languages allow only (just simply enough) endofunctor, that are functors from and to the same category.
 * In this case, the category is the one of the datatypes (in here Type, in order to make it more clear)
 */
public interface EndoFunctor<X extends Type> extends Type {

    /**
     * The basic implementation for any element fx
     * @param map   Transformation function for the type parameter
     * @param fx    Element of the current class
     * @param <Y>   Target type
     * @return      transformed element through map
     */
    <Y extends Type> EndoFunctor<Y> fmap(Function<X,Y> map, EndoFunctor<X> fx);

}
```

If I want to implement a [image: Identity Functor over types] functor, I have to write something like

```
public class Id<X extends Type> implements EndoFunctor<X> {
    protected X witness;
    Id(X witness) { this.witness = witness; }
    @Override
    public <Y extends Type> Id<Y> fmap(Function<X, Y> map, Id<X> fx) {
        return new Id<>(map.apply(fx.witness));
    }
}
```

The problem with this code is that `Id<X>` does not match the type `EndoFunctor<X>`. How could I determine `fmap` in the `EndoFunctor` interface such that if any type `K<T>` implements `EndoFunctor<T>` and a map function `T->U` is given, then `K<U>` is returned as a value, without any typecasting (that is, since I know that my object is an `Id<T>`, then the result of `fmap` "has to be" a `Id<U>`, and hence I downcast the result of type `EndoFunctor<U>` to such type)?

Comment: Is there a reason why you haven't used `EndoFunctor<Y> fmap(Function<X,Y> map)` instead? This way, each instance would use its instance variables. I.e., `return new Id<>(map.apply(this.witness))`.

Comment: Well, I don't think that this observation could answer my question. Your map (`fmap2(x)`) is definable as `fmap(x,this)`, so this does not really solve the type problem.

Comment: By the way, I defined the function in this way in order to make it resemble more the definition of a functor, that is [F:(a->b)->(Fa -> Fb)](http://latex.codecogs.com/gif.download?F%5Ccolon%20%28a%5Cto%20b%29%5Cto%20%28Fa%5Cto%20Fb%29), where F in this case is the EndoFunctor.

Comment: It seemed to me that in your `Id` implementation you were limiting the range of arguments to instances of `Id`. I was trying to understand whether an  `Id` could ever accept an argument of any other Functor type.

Comment: You might want to consider trying this in Scala instead because its type system can actual do it. e.g. `trait Functor[F[_]] { def fmap[A,B](g: A => B)(f: F[A]): F[B] }`

Comment: Good to know. The only problem is that when such functions are called from Java (I have some code that has been already written in Java), such Typecasts are not preserved. Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use [CRTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern):

```
interface EndoFunctor<X extends Type, T extends EndoFunctor<X, T>> extends Type {
    <Y extends Type> EndoFunctor<Y, ?> fmap(Function<X,Y> map, T fx);    
}

class Id<X extends Type> implements EndoFunctor<X, Id<X>> {
    protected X witness;
    Id(X witness) { this.witness = witness; }

    @Override
    public <Y extends Type> Id<Y> fmap(Function<X, Y> map, Id<X> fx) {
        return new Id<>(map.apply(fx.witness));
    }
}
```

Comment: This approach solves other issues (with which I will not bore you) that I have later on on my code. Thanks

Answer (score 8):

> How could I determine fmap in the EndoFunctor interface such that if any type K implements EndoFunctor and a map function T->U is given, then K is returned as a value, without any typecasting (that is, since I know that my object is an Id, then the result of fmap "has to be" a Id, and hence I downcast the result of type EndoFunctor to such type)?

You can't; this is called higher-kinded polymorphism, and Java doesn't support it (very few languages do). Jorn Vernee's answer gets you the closest you can in Java, but that interface allows you to write

```
class NotId<X extends Type> implements EndoFunctor<X, Id<X>> {

    @Override
    public <Y extends Type> ADifferentEndoFunctorAgain<Y> fmap(Function<X, Y> map, Id<X> fx) { ... }
}
```

and won't work if you want to write the code generic over `EndoFunctor`s instead of working with a *specific* `EndoFunctor` like `Id`.

Comment: Actually, I hoped that performing some lifting over types would have helped on that issue. Your answer is formally correct, while the previous one helped me to code. Too bad that I cannot accept two answers at the same time.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is not that `Id<X>` does not match `EndoFunctor<X>`, but that when you have tried to override `fmap` you have made the parameter types more specific, and consequently the method signature no longer matches the method signature of `fmap` in `EndoFunctor`

This means that `Id<X>` in it's current form does not fully implement the `EndoFunctor<X>` interface. When implementing an interface, it must be possible to interact with your class without needing to know that it's a different interface.

Either follow the advice in the comments about removing this method parameter and using the instance variable, or modify the signature in `Id<X>` to `public <Y extends Type> Id<Y> fmap(Function<X, Y> map, EndoFunctor<X> fx)` to make it compatible with the interface.

Comment: Your advice has a similar problem as the one described above: by doing this, I only allow one specific returned type.